# Covariance of integrated Brownian bridge

Tags: stochastic-calculus

How to find the Covariance of $Z(p)$ and $Z(q)$, where $$Z(p)=\int_0^p B(u)du+\int_p^1 \frac{B(u)}{1-u}du$$
and $B(u)$ is the standard Brownian Bridge on $[0,1]$.
My approach is that $Z(p)=\int_0^p B(u)du+\int_p^1 \frac{B(u)}{1-u}du$ is a Gaussian process with mean $0$.
To find the covariance, I proceed as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
Cov(Z(p),Z(q))&=&\int_0^p\int_0^q E[B(u)B(v)]dv du+\int_0^p\int_q^1\frac{E[B(u)B(v)]}{1-u} dv du\\
&+&\int_p^1\int_0^q\frac{E[B(u)B(v)]}{1-u} dv du
+\int_p^1\int_q^1\frac{E[B(u)B(v)]}{(1-u)^2} dv du\\
&=&
\int_0^p\int_0^q [min\{u,v\}-uv]dv du+
\int_0^p\int_q^1\frac{[min\{u,v\}-uv]}{1-u} dv du\\&+&
\int_p^1\int_0^q\frac{[min\{u,v\}-uv]}{1-u} dv du
+\int_p^1\int_q^1\frac{[min\{u,v\}-uv]}{(1-u)^2} dv du.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: its covariance with what?

Comment: if we consider the functional as Z(p), then i am trying to to find Cov(Z(p),Z(q)). thank you...@MarkJoshi

Comment: Looks good, go ahead.

Comment: I am looking forward if I am going in right way or not....@zhoraster..thank you